# Making google maps polygon bigger or smaller

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm having trouble with making polygon (or any google maps shapes) smaller or bigger. I have drawn polygon object. Now I want to make it x% bigger. Any ideas how should I recalculate latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible basic workflow(for polygons/polylines):

1. calculate the center of the shape by creating a LatLngBounds-object that will be extended by the vertices of the shape
2. create a new array for the path of the resized shape
3. iterate over the vertices of the shape and use [`google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) to calculate the new point based on the calculated center,current vertice-point and  the desired fraction
4. push these calculated points to the array for the new path
5. set the path of the shape to the array that has been populated with the calculated points

For a rectangle calculate the southWest nd northEast of the bounds in the same manner.

For a circle apply a new radius based on the desired fraction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'll try it and let you know.